# Javascript - Page slow to show after not being the active tab

Tags: javascript, browser, highcharts, tabs, loading

So I have developed a webpage containing some javascript and a couple of HighChart charts.
The page generally works great, every few seconds data is fetched from the server using an ajax request, and the chart is updated.

The issue happens when I have switched to a different tab for a few minutes and then want to go back. The page can take a very long time to show up. This happens on both Chrome and Firefox.

I couldn't really find out how the browser is handling javascript and page updates in non-active tabs, but it seems to be related at least.

Any ideas on how to improve the time it takes for the page to show?

To be perfectly clear, the page has no visible performance issues while it is the active tab.

Comment: Take a look at these issues from highcharts Github: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/9749, https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/9074.

Comment: It seems like 9749 is relevant, but this issue happens in firefox as well, and the comments on 9749 say it doesn't happen on browsers other then chrome.

Comment: Could you try to overwrite `Highcharts.SVGElement.animate` and remove the added piece of code from this commit: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/commit/25506e537597352ed5a2fa5cd69ef029c3d1c60e? If it doesn't help you could you reproduce this issue in online code editor like jsfiddle?

Comment: This piece of code is not present in my highcharts code. Could that be the issue? this piece of code seems to handle the exact case I am referring to...
Anyway, I will try to create a jsfiddle for that.

Comment: Oh, I see. Yes, it can be the issue. Could you try to add it to your code and check if it solves it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out we froze highcharts just a couple of versions before [this](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/commit/25506e537597352ed5a2fa5cd69ef029c3d1c60e) fix went in.
When we upgraded the version, everything worked great!

Many thanks to @WojciechChmiel for pointing me in the right direction.